# How to print a values (height/width) from a structure declared in a header file C

Tags: c, struct, structure

I try to print a value from a bitmap file. the struct is declared in a header file.
How to access the members and print out their values?

This is the code in the header file. Now I'd like to print the values of the members width and height in the main.c.

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned int   size;
    unsigned int   width;
    unsigned int   height;
    unsigned short planeCnt;
    unsigned short depth;
    unsigned int   compression;
    unsigned int   imageSizeBytes;
    unsigned int   xPelsPerMeter;
    unsigned int   yPelsPerMeter;
    unsigned int   colorsUsed;
    unsigned int   importantColors;

} bmpInfoHeader;
```

I tried doing it like this:

```
    printf("%d", bmpInfoHeader.height);
    printf("%d", bmpInfoHeader.width);
```

but I'm getting these errors:

error C2228: left of '.width' must have class/struct/union

'bmpInfoHeader' : illegal use of this type as an expression

Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: You cannot write `int=123;` You have to make an instance `int i; i = 123;`

Comment: Where are you declaring bmpInfoHeader? Note that this variable as the same name as the structure witch is causing the problem. You need to do bmpInfoHeader bmp = (initialization function);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do something like this:

```
bmpInfoHeader t = { 1, 2 };
printf("%d", t.height);
printf("%d", t.width);
```

`bmpInfoHeader` is a type name, you need to define a variable of this type, such as `t`, initialize it, then access its member by `t.width`.

Comment: Wow you are very good at explaining. I now understand that bmpInfoHeader is a type that should be defined by like you said t. It's printing the values 0 and 2, but should be 47 and 69 pixels. Do you know how come?

Comment: I did not understand what you are trying to say, could you be more specific?

Comment: Yes I will try: The data is read from the bitmap eagle.bmp. When I check the width and height (dimensions) with explorer it says: 69x47 pixels. Those values should be printed on my screen, but instead it prints 0 for height and 2 for width. The following functions are used to read bitmap info:  FILE* openBitmap (char* fileName);
bmpHeader bitmapFileHeader (FILE *file);
bmpInfoHeader bitmapInfoHeader (FILE *file);
int pixels (FILE *file, Bitmap *bitmap, pixel* pixels,
unsigned int numberOfPixels, unsigned int offset);

Comment: Please update your question or ask a new one, state in it explicitly what you did, what you expected, and what you actually got.

Answer (score 1):

You need a variable of struct bmpInfoHeader so that memory will be allocated and there will be some values to print. Now you have only declaration of struct, nothing to print. 
You need access to the variable with type of this struct:

```
bmpInfoHeader bmpInfo;  // memory allocated on the stack
bmpInfo.height = 680;   // height field initialized
//...

printf("%d", bmpInfo.height);
```

Comment: the values are to be read from a bitmap file that is located in ../bitmap The whole code is well written, but I only need to read the bitmapfile information of members height and widht. Thanks for your input